# Storing model or collection-specific views inside model or collection constructors

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I realize there is many solutions to this but I was wondering what the community's opinion is.

I have a series of models and collections. Each model has a number of views like details, edit, print, aside, help, etc. Collections have views that often have the same names (ie: aside, help, etc).

One requirement I have is that I need to structure my code in modules. The application should have no trace of a module's functionality if the module is NOT loaded. This may happen if, say, a user has no permissions to view, edit, etc other users. So the "Users" module would not even be loaded.

So...

I thought a good place to store view definitions for a model could be the model's constructor and for a collection in the collection's constructor. For example:

```
var User = (function(){ // module definition

    // model definition
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            // ...
        }
    },{
        Views: {
            Details: Backbone.View.extend({
                // ...
            }),
            Aside: Backbone.View.extend({
                // ...
            }),
            Help: Backbone.View.extend({
                // ...
            })
        }
    });

    // collection definition
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Model,
        initialize: function() {
            // ...
        }
    },{
        Views: {
            Aside: Backbone.View.extend({
                // ...
            }),
            Help: Backbone.View.extend({
                // ...
            })
        }
    });

    // add more code here

    return { // make model and collection public
        Model: Model,
        Collection: Collection
    };

})(); // end module definition
```

I realize I could have my views live elsewhere but would this approach have any considerable drawbacks that I may not be aware of? Perhaps memory leaks or something less obvious?

Thank you!

Comment: Hm... I guess part of my question, and sorry if this sounds basic, is: when creating an instance, will the "Views" object be copied once per instance or, by having added these to the constructor am I ensuring those definitions are added to memory only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off not adding your views as "class methods" onto your models and collections. Because of the nature of **JavaScript's prototypical inheritance**, you aren't really adding class methods so much as **properties to the constructor functions** for your model types. As to whether or not this is going to cause you issues like memory leaks, I can't say.

I would instead say that, unless you have an unlisted compelling reason for using this structure, **you are better off just grouping your views on simple objects**.

If the goal is to modularize your code I would take advantage of something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or [Marionette modules](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md) or just grouping "related" code in an IIFE.

If you are interested in knowing more about **what exactly happens to the `classProperties`** that are passed into the `Backbone.Model.extend` method then I would recommend looking directly at the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html).

Comment: I didn't know about Marionette. I'll try that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org). With it you should be able to add logic that deals with module loading. In general you should still have a look at it, works great for organising backbone applications, especially with the [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text).

Comment: I have and will use require.js for modularizing my application :) But within a single module I will have at least a model, a collection and views for each. So.. Say I put all that code above into a require.js module, does that approach where I put the views in the constructor make sense?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. The point of MVC (or whatever) is to have everything separated. Try to think of everything as a single component. There will be situations as the application grows where you might need a model and not a view or a view but a different model. Separate things and find another way to enable/disable modules. Just disabling the module in require would be enough. After that you would only need to remove reference to that module from your application (like hiding the button to a disabled view)

Comment: I think I'm getting hung up on naming and where to put certain pieces of the application. Thank you. You're right.